# How to make a chatbot only for searching the excel

Tags: excel, dialogflow-es, chatbot, chatscript

I want to make the simplest chatbot for searching the information much easier.

For example, if I ask John’s major, my chatbot will answer that it is Computer science. So simple.

But I found that if I want to make a chatbot which is answering based on database should through **webhook** thing, and It doesn’t sound easy for me.
Is there any other (easy) way to make chatbot based on excel data or send a query... or whatever databases..

I want to make this on dialogflow!

+If i use chatscript, webhook is not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You need a webhook to connect to your application which can do what you need.
You have 2 options in DialogFlow:

- Webhook URL: to invoke your custom application (here you have all the flexibility you need: access Excel, compute a response, etc..)
- Inline Editor: create a Cloud Function on Google Firebase (I have no experience but I expect you can do almost anything you need - check pricing as it is a cloud service)

Setup #1 is not difficult, the harder part is to manage/access the XLS file programmatically.

Best of luck,
Beppe